# Can not use the USB Camera

Tags: camera, webcam

I'm trying to connect my USB webcam to Raspberry PI 3. First I tried to reach it with `fswebcam image.jpg` command, but it got timed out.

```
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
Adjusting resolution from 384x288 to 352x288.
--- Capturing frame...
Timed out waiting for frame!
No frames captured.
```

Then, I tried to reach it via OpenCV with trying different ports such as: `0,1 /dev/video0, /dev/video1` etc. But it did not work.

When I plug in my camera and use the `dmesg | grep USB*` command I'm getting some information:

```
[  961.147819] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
[  961.278694] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1908, idProduct=2310, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  961.278739] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  961.278760] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB2.0 PC CAMERA
[  961.280180] usb 1-1.3: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 PC CAMERA (1908:2310)
[  961.284227] input: USB2.0 PC CAMERA: USB2.0 PC CAM as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input3
```

Also, when I run the `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` command I'm getting some information to related ports:

```
bcm2835-codec-decode (platform:bcm2835-codec):
    /dev/video10
    /dev/video11
    /dev/video12
    /dev/video18
    /dev/video31
    /dev/media2

bcm2835-isp (platform:bcm2835-isp):
    /dev/video13
    /dev/video14
    /dev/video15
    /dev/video16
    /dev/video20
    /dev/video21
    /dev/video22
    /dev/video23
    /dev/media0
    /dev/media1

USB2.0 PC CAMERA: USB2.0 PC CAM (usb-3f980000.usb-1.3):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
    /dev/media3
```

When I run the `vcgencmd get_camera` command i'm gettin below:

```
supported=1 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
```

I also enabled the legacy camera from `raspi-config`. I use the same camera with Orange PI and it worked without problem. There is only camera plugged in to Raspberry Pi and Raspberry Pi powered by phone adapter.

How can I reach to the camera and take videos/photos? Can you help me out?

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: I added thanks.